# How to target clicked element to a specific element to show its description

Tags: jquery, html

We have blocks with buttons. Each button targets its `[data-description]` to a specific block, which shows the `[data-description]` to its targeted `content-block`. Now I manualy set `if` function, like:

```
if (targetElement == 'text-pack-1')
if (targetElement == 'text-pack-2')
```

And the question is how NOT manualy write if condition, so the each button block knows where its targeted?

```js
function modalBox() {
  $('.list-labels').each(function(i) {
    i++;
    $(this).addClass('pack-' + i);       
  });
  $('.content-block').each(function(i) {
    i++;
    $(this).addClass('text-pack-' + i);       
  });
  
  $('.pack').on('click', function() {
    var targetElement = $(this).data('target')
    
    if (targetElement == 'text-pack-1') {
      var descrip = $(this).data('description')
      $('.text-pack-1').text(descrip)
    }
    if (targetElement == 'text-pack-2') {
      var descrip = $(this).data('description')
      $('.text-pack-2').text(descrip)
    }
    
  })
}

modalBox()
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  margin: 100px;
  background: #39A2AE;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
ul {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.pack {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.content-block {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  margin: 30px 0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-labels"> 
  <li><div class="pack" data-target="text-pack-1" data-description="Button-1">Button-1</a></li>
  <li><div class="pack" data-target="text-pack-1" data-description="Button-2">Button-2</a></li>
  <li><div class="pack" data-target="text-pack-1" data-description="Button-3">Button-3</a></li>
  <li><div class="pack" data-target="text-pack-1" data-description="Button-4">Button-4</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="list-labels">
  <li><div class="pack" data-target="text-pack-2" data-description="Button-5">Button-5</a></li>
  <li><div class="pack" data-target="text-pack-2" data-description="Button-6">Button-6</a></li>
  <li><div class="pack" data-target="text-pack-2" data-description="Button-7">Button-7</a></li>
  <li><div class="pack" data-target="text-pack-2" data-description="Button-8">Button-8</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="content-block">
  
</div>
<div class="content-block">
  
</div>
```

Comment: use $(this) inside the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *massively* simplify the logic here if you relate the `.list-label` elements to the `.content-block` by their index. Try this:

```js
$('.list-labels div').click(function() {
  var $div = $(this);
  var index = $div.closest('.list-labels').index('.list-labels');
  $('.content-block').eq(index).text($div.data('description'));
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  margin: 100px;
  background: #39A2AE;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
ul {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.pack {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.content-block {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  margin: 30px 0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list-labels"> 
  <li><div class="pack" data-description="Button-1">Button-1</div></li>
  <li><div class="pack" data-description="Button-2">Button-2</div></li>
  <li><div class="pack" data-description="Button-3">Button-3</div></li>
  <li><div class="pack" data-description="Button-4">Button-4</div></li>
</ul>

<ul class="list-labels">
  <li><div class="pack" data-description="Button-5">Button-5</div></li>
  <li><div class="pack" data-description="Button-6">Button-6</div></li>
  <li><div class="pack" data-description="Button-7">Button-7</div></li>
  <li><div class="pack" data-description="Button-8">Button-8</div></li>
</ul>

<div class="content-block"></div>
<div class="content-block"></div>
```

As you can see from the example, the first `.list-labels` sets the first `.content-block`, the second sets the second, and so on. The code will work for any number of elements without amendment, and saves on having to create ugly unique classes on the elements, having to have a rigid `data-target` attribute set, and most importantly the `if` statement.